# Plot multiple functions in wolfram mathematica

Tags: plotting

I would like plot function z=f(x) where z=tanh(y) and y=3*sin(x), and function sin(x). So the result will be two graphs.

I tried this:

```
Plot[{z = f[x], z = tanh[y], y = 3*sin[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

But it did not work. Can you help me, please?

Comment: what is $f(x)$ ?  Plot can't plot generic functions like this. (besides, you have other syntax issues)

Comment: Please read the documentation of `Plot`, especially the examples. Then you will know how do others use `Plot`.

Comment: Also, all Mathematica built-in functions begin with capital letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y = 3*Sin[x];
z = Tanh[y];
Plot[{z, Sin[x]}, {x, -2π, 2π}]
```

[image]